# Stretch canvas on a pandas/matplotlib graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following function that makes boxplots given a pandas dataframe:

```
def plot_boxplots(data, ylabel):
    ax = data.plot.box()
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(90)
    plt.tight_layout()
```

The reason I rotate the labels is that the label names can be long, and otherwise overlap one another. The y-axis label can also be long.

In the end, I get figures where the actual boxes are compressed in one fourth of the height of the figure, the space being mainly occupied by labels.

For instance:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "very_very_very_very_long_name_of_first_series" : np.random.normal(loc=-2, scale=2, size=10),
    "very_very_very_very_long_name_of_second_series" : np.random.normal(loc=3, scale=1.5, size=10)})
plot_boxplots(test_df, "vertical_axis_with_long_label")
```

[image: boxplots without enough vertical space]

**How can I stretch the canvas (or however it is named: the part with the boxes) vertically?**

Ideally, I would like to have something automatic, for instance based on a desired proportion between the canvas and the labels part, or some minimal height for the canvas.

---

#### Partial solution

Following comments by [Andrey Sobolev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1027367/andrey-sobolev), I now have something working with a fixed total aspect ratio:

```
def plot_boxplots(data, ylabel):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 12))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    data.plot.box(ax=ax)
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(90)
    plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: Boxplots on a stretched figure]

I'm still interested in a solution to set the canvas size independently of the total figure size.

Comment: isn't it sufficient to set the figure size to more or less vertical aspect ratio?

Comment: Maybe, but how do I do this?

Comment: `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 12))` before you plot anything

Comment: I tried `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 12)); fig.add_axes(fig.add_axes(test_df.plot.box()))`, but I get `ValueError: The Axes must have been created in the present figure`.

Comment: Also tried `fig.axes.append(test_df.plot.box()); ax = fig.axes[0]` and got `IndexError: list index out of range`. Apparently, one cannot append an axis to a figure that way...

Comment: Yet another attempt: `ax = fig.add_subplot(); test_df.plot.box(ax=ax)`, and I get the boxplots in a new figure.

Comment: OK, I had no axis returned. I should use `ax = fig.add_subplot(111)`. Now I have something working better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is often sufficient to adjust figure size in the way it's shown in the comments, but if you want to change the size of the axes, here is one way to do it:

```
ax = plt.axes([x_bl, y_bl, x_tr, y_tr])
```

So, instead of getting the Axes instance from `add_subplot`, you can explicitly add it with `plt.axes`, where `x_bl, y_bl` are the coordinates of bottom left corner, and `x_tr, y_tr` are the coordinates of top right corner of the canvas in Figure coordinates, i.e. `0., 0.` is the bottom left corner of the Figure, and `1., 1.` is the top right corner of the Figure.